# Unable to write to file with phonegap

Tags: iphone, file, cordova

Using the methods found on the [phonegap api](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter) I'm trying to write to a file. This works in Android, but on an iOS device the writer is returning an error. Whenever I call writeFile() it returns an error, and the param passed into writeFail is -1. I cannot see why -1 is being passed into the error function, or why it's even failing to begin with. Has anyone else used the fileWriter on an iOS device, or can you see what I might be doing wrong?

```
function writeFile() {
    var paths = navigator.fileMgr.getRootPaths();
    var writer = new FileWriter(paths[0] + "write.txt");
    writer.onwrite = writeSuccess;
    writer.onerror = writeFail;

    writer.write("some sample text");
    // The file is now 'some sample text'
}

function writeSuccess() {
    console.log("Write has succeeded");
}

function writeFail(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

Comment: What paths does `navigator.fileMgr.getRootPaths()` return?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to use FileWriter and not more simply use LocalStorage (http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-storage-interface)

Comment: navigator.fineMgr.getRootPaths() returns an array `["var/mobile/Applications/{UUID}/Documents",
"/var/mobile/Applications/{UUID}/Library",
"/private/var/mobile/Applications/{UUID}/tmp/"]`. where {UUID} is the unique id for the ios device. @jeff-kelley

Comment: Also, @kris-erickson, we have been using LocalStorage, but we are now wanting a solution that will allow multiple apps to access the same data, which we haven't been able to do with LocalStorage.

Comment: Hi @a.meservy Can you tell me from where does this navigator.fileMgr come from? I am getting following error on that line  TypeError: Result of expression 'navigator.fileMgr' [undefined] is not an object.
Can you please help?

Comment: fileMgr was deprecated a long time ago. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12188444/529323

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but I crawled through the mailing list and finally found the solution:

```
var writer = new FileWriter("write.txt");
```

This is it. Simply *don't* prepend the "Documents"-path. The documentation is wrong on that (still).

And don't forget to not use "readAsDataURL" as it would silently not work (on iOS). Hope I could help you.

Comment: So how then does one write to "~/Library/Caches" or "~/Library/Application Support" if one can't use the base paths from getRootPaths()?

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me (phonegap ver 3.1.0). The FileWriter wanted a full path. Getting the FileSystem object and using its root.fullPath in FileWriter constructor worked. I think Rodrigo's answer on this page looks like the right way to go.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write to a file this is the function(phonegap 2.5)

```
function fileWrite(filePath, text) {
  var onFSWin = function(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile(filePath, {create: true, exclusive: false}, onGetFileWin, onFSFail);
  }
  var onGetFileWin = function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, onFSFail);
  }
  var gotFileWriter = function(writer) {
    writer.write(text);
  }
  var onFSFail = function(error) {
   console.log(error.code);
  }
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSWin, onFSFail);
 }
```