# PhoneGap's navigator.fileMgr always undefined

Tags: ios, file, api, cordova, filewriter

I'm building iOS app with PhoneGap, need to write and read text file to the device.

I followed the steps found here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

Everything works fine, except I cannot use any of the API (I tried file and notification). I am calling:
alert(navigator.fileMgr) but it's always undefined.

I am calling that in the deviceready callback function.

I think I missed some important steps, could anyone have experience in this give me some link/guide/help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you are getting your info but navigator.fileMgr does not exist anymore and hasn't for a long time. We've implemented the W3C File API:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

To get the root path of the file system you would do:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {
    console.log("File system root = " + fileSys.root.fullPath);
}, function() {
    console.log("Could not get file system");
});
```

Examples of how to read/write files are also available on the docs site.

Comment: It's referenced under iOS Quirks here, http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera.

Comment: I just ran into this myself. Not the bug, but the fact that it was documented (2.5.0 docs) and I had no idea what it was.